# The integral test for convergence

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, improper-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x} \cos{(x)}}{x + \sin{(x)}} \,dx $$

I tried with Taylor approximations and dividing the integral into two - from 0 to a and from a to $\infty$ but didn't work well.

Comment: Which obstacle did you find?

Comment: I got it divergant, and according Wolfram it's convergant.

Comment: On $[0,1]$ the integrand is $O(x^{-1/2})$, which is integrable.  On $[1,\infty)$, integrate by parts.

Comment: @MarkViola I need to understand if it's convergant, don't need to evaluate it.

Comment: @VladiStoyanov I'm not suggesting that you try to evaluate it.  I've posted a solution with hints.  Follow the hints and see if you can deduce convergence.

Comment: The denominator vanishes out at infinity points along the
$\displaystyle x$-axis ( where $\displaystyle x + \sin\left(x\right) = 0$ ). Maybe, you should try a $\displaystyle{\tt Principal\ Value}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inasmuch as the integrand has a singularity at $x=0$, you were correct to write the integral for $L>2$ as

$$\int_0^L \frac{\sqrt {x}\cos(x)}{x+\sin(x)}\,dx=\int_0^2 \frac{\sqrt {x}\cos(x)}{x+\sin(x)}\,dx+\int_2^L \frac{\sqrt {x}\cos(x)}{x+\sin(x)}\,dx\tag1$$

**HINTS:**

For the first integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$, note that as $x\to 0$, $\frac{\sqrt {x}\cos(x)}{x+\sin(x)}=O\left(\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}\right)$.  What does this imply?

For the second integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$, integrate by parts with $u=\frac{\sqrt x}{x+\sin(x)}$ and $v=\sin(x)$.  Does the resultant integral converge absolutely as $L\to \infty$?  What can you deduce about the integral of interest?

Answer (score 1):

The integral is not convergence (in the sense of Lebesgue), that is $|f(x)|$, where $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x} \cos x}{x+\sin x}$ is not integrable.
For example, for $\frac{2n-1}{2}\pi\leq x\leq \frac{2n+1}{2}\pi$, $n\geq1$  we have
$$\frac{(2n-1)}{2}\pi-1\leq x+\sin x\leq \frac{(2n+1)}{2}\pi+1$$
and so
$$\frac{\sqrt{(2n-1)\pi}}{(2n+1)\pi+2}|\cos x|\leq |f(x)|\leq \frac{\sqrt{(2n+1)\pi}}{(2n-1)\pi-2}|\cos x|$$
Then
$$\int^{\tfrac{(2n+1)}{2}\pi}_{\tfrac{(2n-1)}{2}\pi}|f(x)|\,dx\geq \frac{\sqrt{(2n-1)\pi}}{(2n+1)\pi+2}2$$
and the series $\sum_n\frac{\sqrt{(2n-1)\pi}}{(2n+1)\pi+2}$ diverges, for its $n$-th term $a_n\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n\pi}}$.

Whether the intergral converges as a proper Riemann integral requires some additional work. One may try to split the integral in pieces forming an alternating series. I leave the details for the OP. I only mention that over $[0,\pi/2]$, $f$ is integrable. Indeed, from $\frac{2}{\pi}\leq \frac{\sin x}{x}\leq 1$ we get that
$$
|f(x)|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{1+\frac{\sin x}{x}}\leq \frac{1}{1+\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
Since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is integrable over $(0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, we conclude that $\int^{\pi/2}_0|f(x)|\,dx<\infty$.